# Angular 2: Delete method not allowed

Tags: javascript, angular

I have a problem with Angular 2 `http.delete` method. My code is below:

```
const headers = new Headers({'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'});

this.http.delete(ConstVarService.url + 'api/tasks/UsunZapis', new RequestOptions({
  headers: headers,
  body: {tasksId: entryId}
})).subscribe((data) => {
  console.log(data)
});
```

And when I execute, I gets the following errors:

```
OPTIONS http://192.168.13.36/pplus-dev/appapi/api/tasks/UsunZapis 405 (Method Not Allowed)
Failed to load http://192.168.13.36/pplus-dev/appapi/api/tasks/UsunZapis: Response for preflight has invalid HTTP status code 405
```

But in Postman everything works, the same URL, Content-Type etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to make a request that is cross-domain the browser does what is called a [pre-flight check](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Preflight_request). You need to return the appropriate CORS headers in order to allow the browser to make requests.

Comment: Ok, so I need change my PHP backend app or something in my angular app? And why postman work's correct but angular not?

Comment: You need to change your PHP backend to return the correct CORS headers. Postman works because it isn't a website, cross-domain is only an issue when making requests from a website.